# Not able to create SQL Select Query

Tags: sql

I have a table

```
DECLARE @tempTable AS TABLE
(
    [State]     VARCHAR(50),
    [Gender]    VARCHAR(6) 
)

INSERT INTO @tempTable
VALUES
('Maharashtra', 'F'),
('Maharashtra', 'M'),
('Maharashtra', 'F'),
('Maharashtra', 'M'),
('Maharashtra', 'F'),
('Bihar', 'M'),
('Bihar', 'M'),
('Bihar', 'F'),
('Bihar', 'M'),
('UP', 'M'),
('UP', 'F'),
('UP', 'F'),
('UP', 'M'),
('MP', 'M'),
('MP', 'M'),
('MP', 'F'),
('MP', 'F')
```

I want to write a query to `SELECT` All [States] Except 'Bihar' And Except 'F' [Gender] in 'Maharashtra' [State]

Please help me write this query.

Comment: Can you please what you have tried? What issue are you facing? It seems that it's homework

Comment: The question is not so clear on what you are trying to do honestly.

Comment: You should tag which dbms are you using. Also you should post what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear exactly what logic you want from your question, but you can try a lot of combinations of select logic easily with SQL fiddle. I believe you want this, but check the fiddle link below and try yourself, if not.

```
select *
from tempTable t 
where t.name != 'Bihar'
  and !(t.name = 'Maharashtra' and gender = 'F')
```

[Example SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0c06d/21)